# Swap DIV code on webpages dependant on URL opened

Tags: html

OK please go easy on me as I am a total newbie to programming but have fairly good HTML and CSS knowledge now.

Basically I have a website http://www.samuivillaretreats.com and on the homepage at the top of the page is a photoalbum using Diapo. This slideshown is held within a DIV and associated with a list of hidden DIVS that make up the info on each slide (URL of slide and caption info). The code for the slideshow was added using a content management system. The .JS files associated with the Diapo slideshow are coded into the HEAD section of the Homepage which is the HEAD code used for every webpage rendedred - not just the homepoage

The homepage slideshow is rendered on every page of the website at the moment. What I want to do is create a slieshow specific to a villa property in the portfolio - so when a user clicks on a specifc holiday property, a slideshow opens in the same position as the homepage slideshow. I was thinking of creating a load of DIVs with unique ID's that holds the information for the specific property and storing these in maybe a specifc HTML file.

So I need to swap the homepage DIV code with specific code for a property. I was thinking that the swap to the correct slideshow could be done by reading the URL as each property has a unique URL ending corresponding to the property.

Lastly, I DO have access to the HEAD section code but this HEAD code is used on every page of the website -i.e I do not have access to a specifc HEAD area for a specific villa property page.

Any ideas would be very grateful - I have read a lot of info on this site about DIV swapping using buttons and via a hash on the end of  URL but nothing that I hve made any sense of.

Answer (score 0):

This code on line 318 in diapo.js on your site selects which images will be in the slideshow

```js
var allImg = new Array(); //I create an array for the images of the slideshow
    $('img', elem).each( function() { 
    allImg.push($(this).attr('src'));
```

What diapo.js does, is retrieving the src attribute from all your img elements (and alternatively afterwards, retrieving background-images of the slider divs for IE 8-.

If you input the images for the slideshow through your CMS, and there is no option to change site-specific to page-specific, then I don't know how to implement it. Maybe ASP or PHP, but I don't know enough of that to advise you about it.

What you could do however, is creating such a div in each page:

```
<div id="slider_img_links">
   <img src="example.jpg"></img>
   <img src="example2.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

..with all images you'd want to show in your slider.

After that, replace the diapo.js code (line 318) I mentioned here with:

```js
var allImg = new Array(); //I create an array for the images of the slideshow
    $('#slider_img_links').children('img').each( function() { 
    allImg.push($(this).attr('src'));
```

or if you don't trust the .each function fully yet,

```js
var allImg = new Array(); //I create an array for the images of the slideshow
var imgLinks = $('#slider_img_links').children('img');
for(i=0;i<imgLinks.length;i++) {
    var oneLink = imgLinks[i].attr('src')
    allImg.push(oneLink);
    }
```

Diapo.js line 322-342 can normally be deleted without consequence.
I haven't tested this, but it should work.

PS (not question-related, but for your site) :

- You have included jQuery (Javascript library) 3x (so you can delete 2
  of them);
- Your CMS generates table-based lay-outs, this article explains why
  this is bad:
  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/